# XML pretty printing/indentation for multiline string

Tags: c#, xml

I am using

```
XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;    
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@"test.xml", xmlWriterSettings);
xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myObject);
```

to get a pretty-printed (indented) xml output. When serializing an object of the class

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlText]
    public string MyText
    { 
        get
        {
            // during serialization insert some newlines into my long
            // text in the hopes of getting a nicely formatted XML file
        }
        set
        {
            // just deserialize the string as it is, missing newlines
            // don't matter for the purposes that the text is used for
        }
    }

    // some other properties
}
```

and after setting

```
myObject.MyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

I get indentation, as requested in the XmlWriterSettings, for all the other XML entities, except the text:

```
    <SurroundingElement>
        <MyClass>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </MyClass>
    </SurroundingElement>
```

whereas I want to get

```
    <SurroundingElement>
        <MyClass>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </MyClass>
    </SurroundingElement>
```

While I understand very clearly why this happens - I am actually misusing the content for formatting it's representation - I wonder if there is another (easy) way to get it formatted "right".

Of course I could also insert tabs during the formatting of the text. But then, strictly speaking, I needed to know the current indentation level while being inside the property getter. In my special case this is not a problem because the document is quite simple, so I can just hardcode adding to every line, say two tabs inside the getter. But in general with arbitrary nesting this wouldn't be an option.

Is there a canonical way to maintain the indentation even for multiline text?

Comment: @BACON: The only answer to the linked question works! Too bad I can't accept it, but at least I have upvoted it to get more hits in the future. I have spent like two hours searching without stumbling over it.